# Binning continuous data and keep correct order - Automatically Organizing Axis Labels in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I simulated a dataset, did some data manipulation (in a very clumsy way) and made the following plot.

Simulate Data:

```
# Step 1 : Simulate Data

set.seed(123)
Hospital_Visits = sample.int(20,  5000, replace = TRUE)
Weight = rnorm(5000, 90, 10)

disease <- c("Yes","No")
disease <- sample(disease, 5000, replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.4, 0.6))
Disease <- as.factor(disease)

my_data = data.frame(Weight, Hospital_Visits, Disease)

my_data$hospital_ntile <- cut(my_data$Hospital_Visits, breaks = c(0, 5, 10, Inf), labels = c("Less than 5", "5 to 10", "More than 10"), include.lowest = TRUE)
```

Data Manipulation:

```
# Step 2: Data Manipulation:

my_data$weight_ntile <- cut(my_data$Weight, breaks = seq(min(my_data$Weight), max(my_data$Weight), by = (max(my_data$Weight) - min(my_data$Weight)) / 10), include.lowest = TRUE)


# Create a dataset for rows where hospital_ntile = 'Less than 5'
df1 <- subset(my_data, hospital_ntile == "Less than 5")

# Create a dataset for rows where hospital_ntile = '5 to 10'
df2 <- subset(my_data, hospital_ntile == "5 to 10")

# Create a dataset for rows where hospital_ntile = 'More than 10'
df3 <- subset(my_data, hospital_ntile == "More than 10")

avg_disease_rate_df1 <- tapply(df1$Disease == "Yes", df1$weight_ntile, mean)
avg_disease_rate_df2 <- tapply(df2$Disease == "Yes", df2$weight_ntile, mean)
avg_disease_rate_df3 <- tapply(df3$Disease == "Yes", df3$weight_ntile, mean)

avg_disease_rate_df1[is.na(avg_disease_rate_df1)] <- 0
avg_disease_rate_df2[is.na(avg_disease_rate_df2)] <- 0
avg_disease_rate_df3[is.na(avg_disease_rate_df3)] <- 0

#transform into dataset

names = names(avg_disease_rate_df1)
rate_1 = as.numeric(avg_disease_rate_df1)
rate_2 = as.numeric(avg_disease_rate_df2)
rate_3 = as.numeric(avg_disease_rate_df3)

# stack data
d1 = data.frame(class = "Less than 5", names = names, rate = rate_1)
d2 = data.frame(class = "5 to 10", names = names, rate = rate_2)
d3 = data.frame(class = "More than 10", names = names, rate = rate_3)

plot_data = rbind(d1, d2, d3)
```

Make Plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=names, y=rate, group = class,  color=class)) + geom_point() + geom_line() +  theme_bw()
```

[image]

**For some reason, the ordering on the x-axis is not in order** - right now it appears randomly, I would like to make it from smallest to largest.

I consulted some references which showed how to change this manually - but **is there some option within ggplot2 that allows for this ordering to be automatically corrected?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**EDIT - you can either do this at the 1) plotting step or at the 2) data manipulation step.**

### 1) - Option for Doing it at the Plotting Step

I think the easiest way to do this is to turn your x-axis variable into a factor and order it.

Right now it's a character

```r
str(plot_data)
```

```r
'data.frame':   30 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ class: chr  "Less than 5" "Less than 5" "Less than 5" "Less than 5" ...
 $ names: chr  "[52.6,59.9]" "(59.9,67.2]" "(67.2,74.5]" "(74.5,81.8]" ...
 $ rate : num  0.6 0.1 0.339 0.399 0.438 ...
```

So you can make it into a factor and then check the levels:

```
plot_data$names <- as.factor(plot_data$names)
levels(plot_data$names)
```

which will show them in a somewhat random order:

```
[1] "(104,111]"   "(111,118]"   "(118,125]"   "(59.9,67.2]" "(67.2,74.5]" "(74.5,81.8]" "(81.8,89.1]" "(89.1,96.3]" "(96.3,104]" 
[10] "[52.6,59.9]"
```

You can re-level them then with the `forcats` library (there are other options but I like this one):

```
plot_data$names <- fct_relevel(plot_data$names,
                               c("[52.6,59.9]", "(59.9,67.2]", "(67.2,74.5]", 
                                 "(74.5,81.8]", "(81.8,89.1]", "(89.1,96.3]", 
                                 "(96.3,104]", "(104,111]", "(111,118]" ))
```

And then your plot will look like this:

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=names, y=rate, group = class,  color=class)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

### 2) - Option for Doing it at the Data Manipulation Step

When you make `weight_ntile` you use `cut()` to which you can ask for an ordered result (`ordered_result = TRUE`) which will get you your ordered factor. But then the rest of the data manipulation will get rid of that ordered factor if left as is. Instead, you could do it all in a pipe series with `dplyr` and `tidyr`. Here's a way to do that:

```r
my_data$weight_ntile <- cut(my_data$Weight, 
                            breaks = seq(min(my_data$Weight), 
                                         max(my_data$Weight), 
          by = (max(my_data$Weight) - min(my_data$Weight)) / 10), 
          include.lowest = TRUE,
          ordered_result = TRUE)

plot_data <- my_data %>% 
  # group by your variables of interest
  dplyr::group_by(hospital_ntile, weight_ntile, Disease) %>% 
  # find number of obs for eacvh group
  dplyr::summarize(
    count = n()
  ) %>% 
  # move these from long to wide for easier calculation
  tidyr::pivot_wider(
    names_from = "Disease", values_from = "count"
  ) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  # make the rate calculation, na.rm = TRUE is important for the edge case of 
  # only one observation (gives the 1.00 rate for 52.6 and 5 to 10)
  dplyr::summarize(
    rate = Yes / sum(Yes, No, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>% 
  # need to ungrouop to use complete()
  ungroup() %>%
  # use complete to fill in what would be NAs, then replace with zeros 
  # instead of NA's (that's the fill argument), this replaces your 
  # `avg_disease_rate_df1[is.na(avg_disease_rate_df1)] <- 0` etc step
  tidyr::complete(., hospital_ntile, weight_ntile, fill = list(rate = 0)) %>% 
  # rename to what you use for the plotting step
  dplyr::rename(
    class = hospital_ntile, names = weight_ntile
  )
```

And then the plot can be made the same way:

```r
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=names, y=rate, group = class,  color=class)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  geom_line() +  
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: @ colebrookson: thank you so much for your answer! it seems like you still had to manually re-order everything ... I wonder if there is someway using the "substr()" function it might be possible to automatically re-order?

Comment: Oh I think I have an answer, you can do it in the cut function but then need to reformat how you do the rest of the data manip. here's how I would do it, i'll edit my answer!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a shorter workflow that keeps the ordering (by using `ordered = TRUE` in your cut steps, and relying on the simpler `dplyr::group_by` grouped aggregation:

```
my_data$hospital_ntile <- cut(my_data$Hospital_Visits, breaks = c(0, 5, 10, Inf), 
                              labels = c("Less than 5", "5 to 10", "More than 10"),
                              ordered_result = TRUE, include.lowest = TRUE)
  
  my_data$weight_ntile <- cut(my_data$Weight, 
                              breaks = seq(min(my_data$Weight), 
                                           max(my_data$Weight), 
                                           by = (max(my_data$Weight) - min(my_data$Weight)) / 10), 
                              include.lowest = TRUE, ordered_result = TRUE)

my_data |>
  dplyr::group_by(hospital_ntile, weight_ntile) |>
  dplyr::summarize(avg_disease_rate = mean(Disease == "Yes"), .groups = "drop") |>
  tidyr::complete(hospital_ntile, weight_ntile, fill = list(avg_disease_rate = 0)) |>
  ggplot(aes(weight_ntile, avg_disease_rate, color = hospital_ntile, group = hospital_ntile)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

---

Starting from your `plot_data`, we can extract the start and end into separate columns, and then make the `names` be an ordered factor in order of the parsed numeric value of `start`.

The reason your original plot isn't showing up as you expect is because the ranges are being interpreted as text (ie character data) and character data is always sorted alphabetically in R.

```
plot_data |>
  tidyr::separate(names, c("start", "end"), sep = ",", remove = FALSE) |>
  dplyr::mutate(names = forcats::fct_reorder(names, readr::parse_number(start))) |>
  ggplot(aes(x=names, y=rate, group = class,  color=class)) + 
  geom_point() + geom_line() + theme_bw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also simply bin your data using `round` (**Plot 1**). Or create custom bins with `plyr::round_any`.

However, I think what you're effectively asking for is a moving average which is commonly used in time series. And here lies the crux of the problem: By visualising  averages over ranges of your weight (your x) you are suggesting a dimension of your data that simply doesn't exist (a relation/dependency within your weights).

**Plot 2** shows an option of showing the moving average of your aggregated rates based on your rounded weight bins (using `tidyquant::geom_ma`). Although it "averages averages", I think it is a cleaner way to address your approach.

**Plot 3** is a suggestion for a different visualisation altogether. It does not require any data manipulation and will therefore be the most accurate representation of your data. The story is getting a different twist though.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_rate <- my_data %>%
## count yes/no disease for rounded weights
  mutate(weight = round(Weight)) %>%
  count(hospital_ntile, weight, Disease) %>%
  ## calculate rate per weight, this does not take into account number of visits!
  group_by(weight) %>%
  mutate(rate = sum(Disease == "Yes")/ n()) 

## plot the rate directly
ggplot(df_rate, aes(x = weight, y = rate, color = hospital_ntile)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

```
## arguably better to use a moving average
ggplot(df_rate, aes(x = weight, y = rate, color = hospital_ntile)) +
  tidyquant::geom_ma(n =  10, lty  = 1)
```

[image]

```r
# however, with the above visualisation you're suggesting a relation that does not exist.
## What you (possibly) actually want to show, is how the distribution is of weight in people with disease and people without. (?)
## Better then do a scatter plot, or show the distribution in a violin plot
ggplot(my_data, aes(x = hospital_ntile, y = Weight)) +
  ggforce::geom_sina(alpha = .5, stroke = 0, size = 1) +
  labs(x = "Hospital visits") +
  facet_grid(~Disease)
```

[image]